# Paste Chart and Change Size in Power Point - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint, paste

I'm trying paste a chart in PowerPoint using the command:

```
PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"
```

It's working very well, but when I try to change size and position the code don't make effect in chart properties and don't return errors. 
When I use the command:

```
Shapes.Paste.Select
```

I can change and resize the chart, but don't work for me because I want "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting". 
What are my mistakes?

My full code
    With PPSlide

```
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

    PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"

    '.Shapes.Paste.Select

    With PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width = 680.314961
        .Height = 453.543307
        .Left = 19.8425197
        .Top = 56.6929134
    End With
```

Comment: Your best bet is to make the chart in Excel the size you need for the PowerPoint chart to be the desired size. If you need the Excel chart to be one size and the PowerPoint chart another size, make a copy of the Excel chart in Excel and resize it (or change the size of the Excel chart, copy and paste into Ppt, then revert to the original size). It sounds excessive, but consider the amount of time you've tried to make one chart do double duty.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```
Dim oSh As Object ' or PowerPoint.Shape if you've set a reference to PPT
Dim lSlideIndex As Long

lSlideIndex = 1

CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"
Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(lSlideIndex).Shapes(ActivePresentation.Slides(lSlideIndex).Shapes.Count)

With oSh
    .Left = 0
    .Width = 100
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this, but doesn't work. Seems that the presentation doesn't update the shapes numbers. I tried to this:

```
lSlideIndex = oPPtApp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex

MsgBox oPPtApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(lSlideIndex).Shapes.Count

oPPtApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"

MsgBox oPPtApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(lSlideIndex).Shapes.Count
```

The command is executed and the shape entered, but the msgbox returns the same value before and after the command. "oPPtApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso" But when I run in different routines, the numbers have been updated. As if I run a routine to the command "oPPtApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso" and one for resizing shapes works perfectly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Or edit the original post (which'd allow for formatting the further example code.  And thanks guitarthrower for catching my failure to do that.  Sergio, when you run this code, is PPT in normal editing mode or in slide show view?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a common problem when calling ExecuteMso in PowerPoint.  Try inserting:

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

right after the ExecuteMso() command.  That works in most (but not all, in my experience) situations.

If MSFT would simply expose these paste methods and other thing (like Undo) in the object model, that would avoid the need to call ExecuteMso and make like easier for developers.